# Error in creating SEQUENCEs when restoring the PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-restore

*UserX* has following grants:

```
CREATE ROLE "UserX" LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass';
CREATE DATABASE "DBX" WITH OWNER="UserX" ENCODING='UTF8' TABLESPACE=pg_default CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "DBX" TO "UserX";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO "UserX";
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "UserX";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO "UserX";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCES TO "UserX";
```

I get following errors when trying to restore its dump to other database:

```
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE "public.tblX_Id_seq"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 218; 1259 438745 SEQUENCE tblX_Id_seq UserX
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"
LINE 2:     AS integer
            ^
    Command was: CREATE SEQUENCE "tblX_Id_seq"
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACH...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "tblX_Id_seq" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE "tblX_Id_seq" OWNER TO "UserX";


pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY "public.tblX_Id_seq"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3569; 0 0 SEQUENCE OWNED BY tblX_Id_seq UserX
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "tblX_Id_seq" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER SEQUENCE "tblX_Id_seq" OWNED BY "tblX"."Id";

...

pg_restore: creating DEFAULT "public.tblX Id"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2995; 2604 438750 DEFAULT tblX Id UserX
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "tblX_Id_seq" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY "tblX" ALTER COLUMN "Id" SET DEFAULT nextval('"tblX_Id_seq"'::regclass);

...

pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET tblX_Id_seq
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 3607; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET tblX_Id_seq UserX
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "tblX_Id_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('"tblX_Id_seq"', 1573, true);
                                 ^
    Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('"tblX_Id_seq"', 1573, true);
```

Any suggestion on what I do wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are trying to restore a dump from a v10 database into an older version of PostgreSQL (`CREATE SEQUENCE ... AS` is new in v10).

That is not supported and won't work. You can create an SQL script with `pg_restore` and edit it manually. Or upgrade the destination database.

Comment: It turns out this wasn't all that hard, at least for my particular use case.  I got by with: `pg_restore -F c --clean --if-exists dumpfile | sed -e '/AS integer/d' > loadme.sql`  Obviously your luck depends on usage of any 10.x specific features, but if you're not...

Comment: Right, that's why it is better to go the supported way and using `pg_dump` from v10 to dump an older database that you want to load into v10.

Answer (score 8):

I have taken these notes:

> #### SUPPORT ALL COMPRESSED DATABASE
>
> pg_dump -U {usuario} -h {host} -W {database} | gzip -c > archivo.gz
>
> #### RESTORE FROM BACK GZIP
>
> gunzip -c {archivo.gz} | psql -h {host} -U postgres {database}
>
> #### RESTORE FROM GZIP BACKUP FROM v10 to v9.x
>
> gunzip -c {archivo.gz} | sed -e '/AS integer/d' | psql -U postgres -h {host} -W {database}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that this is an international forum and that questions and answers should be written in English.

Comment: Vow that really saved my day. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution to restore the database from higher version to a lower version.
if sequence error occurs during restore the database just remove As integer from dump.sql file and restore it will solve the sequence error.

For Example:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE "tblX_Id_seq"
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACH...
```

Remove AS integer

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "tblX_Id_seq"
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACH...
```