# After restoring my database serial removed from column in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql lost the autoincrement feature after a restore. My database was created on Windows 10 (v 10.1) and I restored it to Postgresql on Ubuntu (v 9.6). Now that I posted the question I saw that the versions are different. I didn't use any obscure feature, only tables, functions, and columns with serials. Also, the restore process didn't complain about anything. I checked the dump options but I couldn't find anything that caused the problem.

With Pgadmin right-clicking the table > scripts > create a script on my original table gives this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.produto
(
    produto_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('produto_produto_id_seq'::regclass),
    ...

);
```

In my server, the restored database. It seems it lost the feature.

```
CREATE TABLE public.produto
(
        produto_id integer NOT NULL,
        ...

);
```

Comment: I notice the problem when my functions started to fail. "produto_id" cannot be null.

Comment: You are importingto an older version (and probably ignoring some errors). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49209191/905902

Comment: A workaround could be: dump the DDL and the copy/data separately, and do some serious editing.Or: upgrade the target to Postgres-10.x

Answer (score 2):

You didn't check for errors during restore of the database; there should have been a few.

A dump of a table like yours will look like this in PostgreSQL v10 (this is 10.3 and it looks slightly different in 10.1, but that's irrelevant to this case):

```
CREATE TABLE public.produto (
    produto_id integer NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE public.produto OWNER TO laurenz;

CREATE SEQUENCE public.produto_produto_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE public.produto_produto_id_seq OWNER TO laurenz;

ALTER SEQUENCE public.produto_produto_id_seq
    OWNED BY public.produto.produto_id;

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.produto
    ALTER COLUMN produto_id
    SET DEFAULT nextval('public.produto_produto_id_seq'::regclass);
```

Now the problem is that `AS integer` was introduced to `CREATE SEQUENCE` in PostgreSQL v10, so that statement will fail with a syntax error in 9.6.

What is the consequence?

- The table is created like in the first statement.
- The third statement creating the sequence fails.
- All the following statements that require the sequence will also fail.

**Note:** It is not supported to downgrade PostgeSQL with dump and restore.

The solution is to manually edit the dump until it works, in particular you'll have to remove the `AS integer` or `AS bigint` clause in `CREATE SEQUENCE`.