# PostgreSql : ERROR: relation "sequence" does not exist while restoring from dump file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump, postgresql-10

I get the following error while restoring database from dump file on server:

> ERROR:  relation "table_id_seq" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('table_id_seq', 362, true);

- my local psql version is 10.2
- server psql version is 9.6.8

Here is my dump command:

```
pg_dump -U username -h localhost db_name > filename.sql
```

Here is my restore command on server:

```
psql -U username -h localhost db_name < filename.sql
```

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Did you inspect the dump for the sequence? Are there other errors in the output?

Comment: @clemens i'm not sure if my dump file has sequence or not. Could you please help?

Comment: Duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49252654/2235885

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After I got information from @clemens and make some research I found that, in my dump file on section `CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq` has a statement `AS integer` that why when I restored into new database it did not create the `nextval()` for the sequence. If I remove the statement `AS integer` from the `CREATE SEQUENCE` section it works find.

In my dump file:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

Remove `AS integer` from dump file

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

Comment: the problem was that you generate the dump on postgres 10 and restore it on a lower version where the syntax "AS data_type" is not avalable

Comment: @gagalago thank you for your command. I will be careful about version next time.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the sequence checking is case-sensitive. That's why I was getting the relation error. So maybe it helps some people like me who end up desperately here. I've used a double-quote inside the single quotation mark in the SQL statement.

```sql
SELECT nextval('"USER_ID_seq"');
```

There're some examples in the official documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-sequence.html

Comment: This really did save me a lot of time. Thank you!

Comment: Oh ffs this was the answer for me, thank you brother

Answer (score 4):

You can open the dump file with any text editor (Notepad, Vim, etc.). Search for `table_id_seq`. You should find a statement like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq ...
```

If it is missing then there is something strange with your dump. You might fix that by adding

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq;
```

immediately in front of the statement

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('table_id_seq', 362, true);
```

from the error message.

But this is just a hack. You were supposed to find out why the dump made that mistake. But that requires more information.

Comment: In my dump file has CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq ... but it's still error.

Comment: @Saly: So you should look into the output if there are any errors. You may add `SET client_min_messages TO NOTICE`to increase the log level.